# JavaScript Regex not catching what it should

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a JavaScript Regular expression, it works as desired in an online regex tester but putting it to use does not work the regex: `const classNameReg= new RegExp('\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}', 'g')`

I pass all of the text below as a single string and am using that regex to split the string to make an array of css classes as shown below, but what I get returned is the whole entire string as one element in the array i first tried it like this `let arrOfClasses = css.split(classNameReg.constructor)` and then like this `let arrOfClasses = css.split(classNameReg)` and then I tried this `let arrOfClasses = css.split(/\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}/g)` which gave me an array of just the class name part so `.c-value-prop-box__icon {` and a bunch of white space elements. Im super new to RegEx just started two days ago, what am I doing wrong

```
.c-btn--vertical-center {
  align-self: center; }

.c-btn.c-btn--sm {
  min-width: 80px;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400; }

 a.c-btn.c-btn--sm {
    height: 24px; }

button.c-btn.c-btn--sm {
    min-height: 24px; }

.c-btn.c-btn--md {
  padding: 9px 32px;
  font-weight: 600; }

a.c-btn.c-btn--md {
    height: 32px; }

button.c-btn.c-btn--md {
    min-height: 32px; }
```

etc.

Comment: Did you mean to use `match`? `css.match(/\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}/g)`?

Comment: Try changing `new RegExp('\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}', 'g')` to `/\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That seems to be correct. I suggest you submit that as an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I am actually puzzled by the current approach. If the file consists of these CSS classes, maybe it will be easier to split with a double+ line break? Something like **[`.split(/(?:\r?\n){2,}/)`](https://jsfiddle.net/tv4n8y5v/1/)**. Also, I see no point in using `\.?` since it is optional, `.+` will match this anyway.

Comment: @lilezek Worked perfeclty thank you!!

Comment: @GavynCaldwell: You actually used the `/\.?.+{[\S\s]+?}/g`, right? But only with `split`? Does `.split(/(?:\r?\n){2,}/)` return the expected results?

Comment: Could do it without a regex: `const rules = classes.split('}').map(c => c.trim() + '}' ).filter(c => c.length != 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look something more like the following (though this may not be perfect, either).

```
(\S+)\s*\{([^}]*)\}
```

In this example I escaped the curly brackets, since they're generally used to indicate an interval quantifier. I included 2 capturing groups to get the element name and then the content. It's generally better practice not to use the dot, but to be more specific. In the example, \S matches anything that's not whitespace.  The [^}] matches anything that's not a closing curly bracket, but if CSS can contain nested curly brackets (I don't know at the moment), this would not be sufficient.

A good site for learning regex is rexegg.com. Also, regular-expressions.info is very useful.